# Why did Arthur Weasley only rent the campsite for one night?

Tags: harry-potter

We know that a Quidditch game can last indefinitely, and we know there are examples of the Quidditch World Cup lasting a week or more.

If so, why did Arthur Weasley only rent the campsite by the World Cup for one night only?

> *‘Aye,’ said Mr Roberts, consulting a list tacked to the door. ‘You’ve got a space up by the wood there. **Just the one night?’**
>
>   ‘That’s it,’ said Mr Weasley.*

If it was likely to take longer than a day, shouldn't he have left the rental open-ended?

Comment: He's not a wealthy man. And those long Quidditch matches are quite exceptional

Comment: For the same reason a working man might buy a one-day ticket for a Cricket test-match lasting 5 days.

Comment: we see he planned to stay, because Ron said he hoped it lasted a while, and Arthur didn't correct him.

Comment: "a while" can just mean "I hope the Seeker doesn't catch the Snitch 45 seconds after the beginning"

Comment: It's certainly possible that *all* of the wizards have booked their pitches for one night. They'll just obliviate the farmer if it runs over into a second day.

Comment: @Jenayah he says that in reference to a multi-day game

Comment: Might want to include that in the question then, it seems relevant :)

Answer (score 25):

The implication seems to be that the Weasleys are perfectly ready for the game to last multiple days.

> ‘Look at the time,’ Mrs Weasley said suddenly, checking her wristwatch. ‘You really should be in bed, the whole lot of you, you’ll be up at the crack of dawn to get to the Cup. Harry, if you leave your school list out, I’ll get your things for you tomorrow in Diagon Alley. I’m getting everyone else’s. **There might not be time after the World Cup, the match went on for five days last time.’**
>   ‘Wow – hope it does this time!’ said Harry enthusiastically.
>   ‘Well, I certainly don’t,’ said Percy sanctimoniously. ‘I shudder to think what the state of my in-tray would be if I was away from work for five days.’

That being the case, the most obvious explanation is that they and their fellow wizards are planning to simply overstay, safe in the knowledge that with the muggle campsite owner's memory being altered so often (ten times a day), Mr Roberts is hardly going to notice a little thing like *what day it is* when he's already not noticed that that there are tens of thousands of wizards staying on his campground.

Comment: Great answer! :)

Comment: Or they'll pay for additional nights if they end up being required. The Ministry isn't going to want Muggles trying to turn up halfway through the match, so all of the spaces should be free to have their rentals extended.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist that was basically what i was asking

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - If any pesky muggles turn up, they'll just get brainwiped and sent home.